# How JDK construct three compact profiles

Tags: java, api

Java 8 provided three candidate compact profiles in its API documentation. Does anyone know how API designers select packages for each compact profile? Do they have any criterion?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to understand what is there in every compact profile. [Compact Profiles](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/compactprofiles/compactprofiles.html)

And if you want to know which compact profile is required (minimum) for a particular class, you can use `jdeps` like;

`jdeps -P YOUR_CLASS_NAME.class`

```
YOUR_CLASS_NAME.class -> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar (compact1)
   com.vtb.audit.domain (YOUR_CLASS_NAME.class)
      -> java.io                                            compact1
      -> java.lang                                          compact1
```

And this tells that minimum compact profile required for this particular class is `compact1`